# How do I run the random.randint function multiple times?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a dice roller in Python for Warhammer 40,000, and the end goal is for the user to input their Ballistic Skill (and any modifiers), the number of attacks, their Strength, the opponent's Toughness, and other stats. The program will use these stats and complete the following.

1. Generate a number of random integers equal to the number the user specified as the number of attacks.
2. Compare these to the Ballistic Skill. Any integers that are greater than or equal to the BS are passed.
3. Test these against the target's Toughness (this will be summarized in a later question).
4. Test the successes against the target's save.
5. Calculate damage.

Right now, I have this smidgen of code.

```
ballistic: int = input("What is your Ballistic Skill? Please answer in this format: '3'.")

shots: int = input('How many shots will your weapon be firing? Answer as a number.')

print("Rolling dice to hit now. Please wait...")

hits = random.randint(1, 6)
```

Note the declaration of the variable "hits"- this is important.

The question is: How do I run the `random.randint` function a number of times equal to the variable "shots"?

Comment: To answer the question in the title, you can use `for` loops. I would highly recommend going through a python tutorial. There are many online.

Answer (score 2):

Jakub pointed out that  in Python a `for` loop is typically what you would use to repeat an operation a specified number of times.  Here is a very basic implementation to give you a feel for how that works.

EDIT 1: Updated Example 1 to print hits only if the value is equal to or greater than the ballistic value.

EDIT 2: Didn't modify the code, but modified the inputs (bumped number of shots up from 10 to 20) to better illustrate the relationship between `ballistics` and `hits`.

Example 1:

```
import random

ballistic = int(input("Enter Ballistic Skill: "))
shot_count = int(input("Enter number of shots: "))

for shot in range(shot_count):
    hits = random.randint(1, 6)
    if hits >= ballistic:
        print(hits)
```

Output:

```
Enter Ballistic Skill: 3
Enter number of shots: 20
3
4
5
6
5
4
5
6
4
4
3
```

One problem with the simple approach is that the value of `hits` is lost at the end of the loop.  That may be okay for what you are doing, but sometimes you want to build a list of something and keep it around for use after the loop.  To do that, there is a more advanced technique called list comprehension that is often used, but for illustration purposes we can just build out the example above.

Example 2:

```
import random

shot_count = int(input("Enter number of shots: "))

hits_list = []

for shot in range(shot_count):
    hits = random.randint(1, 6)
    hits_list.append(hits)

print(hits_list)
```

Output:

```
Enter number of shots: 3
[1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is extraordinarily helpful. Thank you! Just one more thing- at the same time as it is rolling the number of shots, I want the program to compare those against the number the user inputted as the Ballistic Skill, and only print the ones that are greater than or equal to that number. How would I go about that?

Comment: I updated the example to show how to do it using an `if` statement.  You can make a lot of progress in Python with just loops and conditionals - go forth and conquer!

Comment: I found an error here. Rather than compare the value of the die to ballistic, it's comparing the NUMBER of dice to ballistic, i.e. the program will only return a number of values equal to ballistic.

Comment: It may be a variable naming thing. In my example shots is the number of dice rolls and hits is the value of any given roll.